# SQL Query Retrieving Latest Row When Other Columns Are Equal

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble figuring out the SQL statement to retrieve a specific set of data. Where all columns are equal except the last update date, I want the most recent. For example.

```
Book    Author   Update
John    Foo      1/21/2010
John    Foo      1/22/2010
Fred    Foo2     1/21/2010
Fred    Foo2     1/22/2010
```

What's the query that retrieves the most recent rows? That is, the query that returns:

```
Book    Author   Update
John    Foo      1/22/2010
Fred    Foo2     1/22/2010
```

TIA,
Steve

Comment: What flavor of SQL? And are there other columns in the table that need to be compared besides the ones shown?

Comment: You guys rock! Thanks for all the answers. Tom H. was first in the door with the answer. BTW, your assumption was correct that I needed more from the query. Thanks for second query. That's actually what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    book,
    author,
    MAX(update)
FROM
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    book,
    author
```

This only works in this particular case because *all* of the other columns have the same value. If you wanted to get the latest row by book, but where the author (or some other column that you will retrieve) might be different then you could use:

```
SELECT
    T.book,
    T.author,
    T.update
FROM
    (SELECT book, MAX(update) AS max_update FROM My_Table GROUP BY book) SQ
INNER JOIN My_Table T ON
    T.book = SQ.book AND
    T.update = SQ.max_update
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it up

```
    DROP TABLE #tmpBooks  
    CREATE TABLE #tmpBooks  
    (
        Book    VARCHAR(100),
        Author  VARCHAR(100),
        Updated DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo', 'Bar', '1/1/1980')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo', 'Bar', '1/1/1990')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo', 'Bar', '1/1/2000')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo', 'Bar', '1/1/2010')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo2', 'Bar2', '1/1/1980')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo2', 'Bar2', '1/1/1990')
    INSERT INTO #tmpBooks VALUES ('Foo2', 'Bar2', '1/1/2000')

    SELECT   Book, Author, Max(Updated) as MaxUpdated
       FROM  #tmpBooks
       GROUP BY Book, Author
```

Results:

```
Book            Author          MaxUpdated
--------------- --------------- -----------------------
Foo             Bar             2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
Foo2            Bar2            2000-01-01 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Sorry, bud, this is not valid SQL.  It looked so tempting that I tried it.  *"Column 'Update' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

Comment: Indeed... the earlier syntax (HAVING Updated = MAX(Updated)) would be nice when there are other rows that you want to get, but alas the only way to express that is more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This will get what you asked for, but something tells me it's not what you want.

```
SELECT Book, Author, MAX(Update)
  FROM BookUpdates
 GROUP BY Book, Author
```

Is there more to the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (don't have the data to test on but it should work):

```
SELECT
    bu.Book,
    bu.Author
FROM
    BookUpdates bu
        JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(Updated) as Date FROM BookUpdates) max
WHERE
    bu.Updated = max.Date;
```